# Sub tabs similar to Media library

Tags: views, 8

I am trying to replicate the user interface Media library provides in 8.8.

I've created a view with 2 displays:

View 1:

Menu tab where Parent is "Content"

`/admin/content/media-image`

View 2:

`/admin/content/media-image-shared`

No menu in the Views UI.

I've then defined:

```
custom_media.image_space:
  title: 'Images'
  route_name: view.media.page
  parent_id: view.media.page
  weight: 20

custom_media.image_shared:
  title: 'Shared images'
  route_name: view.media.shared
  parent_id: view.media.page
  weight: 20
```

The main tab next to Content / Media / Files / Images is present. However, the subtabs on my view Images are not displayed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

The parent must be the Views local task id for both definitions.

So `parent_it` should be `views_view:view.media.page`